# Can Java Set objects be modified in place?

Tags: java, set, treeset

I am using a TreeSet but am wondering more specifically for Set in general if it is okay to modify an entry without removing it or if this creates unpredictable behavior. Basically, does the Set/TreeSet reorganize itself internally if it is modified even if the modified entry is not removed and re-added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, collections with some kind of internal structure don't watch for changes in their elements, and their structure will be destroyed if you modify the elements (in ways that change the property that the structure is based on). This holds for `TreeSet` as well. However, a `HashSet` will handle changes if the `hashCode()` method of its elements is implemented properly, as the contract for that method specifies that an object's hash code may never change. (Technically, `Comparator` and `Comparable` are also supposed to have the property that the result of `compare(a, b)` (or `a.compareTo(b)`) should always be the same for the same two elements, and if your elements or `Comparator` satisfy that, `TreeMap` is safe, too.)

In short: if you put elements into a structured collection, make sure that you don't make changes that affect the property/behavior that the collection bases its structure on. Which property/behavior this is depends on the structure.

You could, however, implement this kind of behavior yourself by using the Observer pattern: your elements could be observable, and you could write a wrapper class for your collection that listens to changes in its elements. Whenever an element changes, you remove it and then insert it back in. Most likely, you would need two notifications: one before the change (remove) and one after the change (add).

Comment: when you say "the result of compare(a, b) (or a.compareTo(b)) should always be the same" do you mean that these two methods should always return the same result as each other or that throughout the life of any two objects any time these comparisons are made should return the same result?

Comment: The latter. If you have a `Comparable` class, there's usually no point in creating a `Comparator` for it unless the `Comparator` performs a different kind of comparison.

Comment: That's interesting. My implementation is using a Disk object to store a List of Integers representing file sizes on a Disk and the Disks are compared based on most remaining space. So are you saying then that using Comparable is not appropriate since I will be adding files to each Disk throughout the life of the program and thus a comparison between any two disks is subject to change? What is the correct approach then?

Comment: I think the "ideal" implementation of a `Comparator`/`Comparable` should ensure that the comparison result for two given objects remains constant, but in practice, that rule is often not followed - however, like I said, most collections assume that it has been followed. So it's fine to make a `Comparator` like you describe; just don't use it with collections without taking extra precautions.